# A good Javascript API reference documentation related to browsers and DOM

Tags: javascript, api, reference

I am looking for a good API documentation for Javascript especially related to browsers and DOM. I am not looking for any kind of Javascript tutorial, but simply a documentation for all standard Javascript classes and for classes used in web browsers.

Something similar to Java's Javadoc ( http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/ )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about the standards?

1. [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/DOM2-Core.pdf) (W3C)
2. [DOM2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/DOM2-Events.pdf) (W3C)
3. [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/DOM2-HTML.pdf) (W3C)
4. [DOM2 CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Style-20001113/DOM2-Style.pdf) (W3C)

And for javascript itself:

5. [Standard ECMA-262 ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (ECMA)

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401969/javascript-reference-for-offline-browsing) answer for an updated list.

Answer (score 9):

[Gecko DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference)

[JavaScript Kit - DOM Reference](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/)

[And many more](http://www.google.com/search?q=dom+reference).

Answer (score 7):

I'm rather fond of [Got API](http://www.gotapi.com/html), which lets you see easily see api docs about all the various pieces of web development.

Comment: This site would be great if someone bothered to keep it up-to-date.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/

The DOM section of it is probably what you look for, alongside with Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

One of the best sites i came across was   http://www.quirksmode.org/

http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

Compares major browsers’ CSS and JavaScript capabilities, as well as their adherence to the W3C standards.

**Added 18/01**

When can I use...  http://caniuse.com/

Compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG and more in desktop and mobile browsers

Answer (score 1):

specific to jQuery I quite like [visualjquery.com](http://visualjquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

I find that when working a lot with these things, nothing beats having a book (which automatically falls open on the 2-3 most popular places due to wear & tear). Nothing beats the [rhino book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992/?CMP=AFC-ak_book&ATT=JavaScript%3A+The+Definitive+Guide), which also has good coverage on what differences you can expect from different browsers. Get the latest edition.

Comment: Note for those reluctant to _read a book_: you can buy electronic version of O'Reilly books :), available in several formats.

Comment: I know it's really *so* 1900's, but this is the only book I own that is totally worn to pieces. I'm kind-of waiting for a new edition because my current book is worn out. Reinforced with gaffa in the spine.