# A good reference site for DOM/Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A good Javascript API reference documentation related to browsers and DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555726/a-good-javascript-api-reference-documentation-related-to-browsers-and-dom)

I've searched Google a bit & can't find a good reference for DOM/Javascript. What I would like is a page that shows lists of all the objects & if you click them you get to see which methods and attributes they have.

What one is your favorite?

Sort of like this one for actionscript:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/class-summary.html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript

Comment: A good site to reference is http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html, although I don't think it's exactly what you're looking for. Good information though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 0):

I used this a while ago

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/CatalogJavaScriptReference.htm