# Where is home page for JavaScript standard committee body and standard texts?

Tags: javascript

I totally frustrate. SO, Wikipedia and MDN doesn't tell where is JavaScript standard committee
home page and standard texts. You may found a lot of tables:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference#JavaScript.2FBrowser_support_history
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript#Versions
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Version_correspondence

which refer to JavaScript 1.1/1.2/1.3/.../1.8.

This page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference#JavaScript.2FBrowser_support_history

have links to standard changelog. But where can I found standard body to compare myself?

**PS.** As I understand ECMAScript standard related to JavaScript standard (or agreement) but not same, so please don't put link to **ECMA**!!

**PPS.** These links for related questions (but they are not same with my!!):

- [A good Javascript API reference documentation related to browsers and DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555726/a-good-javascript-api-reference-documentation-related-to-browsers-and-dom)
- [Javascript reference for offline browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401969/javascript-reference-for-offline-browsing)
- [Where can I find a good Javascript/DOM reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003891/where-can-i-find-a-good-javascript-dom-reference)
- [What are some of the best reference sites for HTML and JavaScript programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823718/what-are-some-of-the-best-reference-sites-for-html-and-javascript-programming)
- [What is the best online javascript/css/html/xhtml/dom reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918/what-is-the-best-online-javascript-css-html-xhtml-dom-reference)

Comment: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/versions-of-javascript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard for Javascript itself. The standard is ECMAScript, and JavaScript is one (the first) implementation of it.

Comment: But if there are no standard or description how is it possible to distinct JavaScript 1.3 from 1.5?? Nobody can't write code if it don't have a list of supported functions and objects!!

Comment: @gavenkoa: You can find information about the Javascript implementation on the Mozilla website.

Comment: I know about this source. But do IE and Chrome developers read MDN wiki pages before implementing new JavaScript 1.x version? Unlikely. Or they just join together I decide feature-set on upcoming version? In this case they have document that describe changes. I am looking for such kind of documents which provide compatibility between implementations.

Comment: @gavenkoa: IE and Chrome have their own implementations of ECMAScript, The Microsoft implementation is named JScript, and the Chrome implementation is named V8. The standard that each has to lean on is ECMAScript, not Javascript, so they only implement parts from Javascript (and other implementations) that they want to support. Although Javascript has a leading role in the development, it's only when features have been added to the ECMAScript standard that they are formally part of the standard.

Comment: The definite source for each implementation would be their own documentation, but the MDN wiki also contains some information about the compatibility for the other implementations.

Comment: Oh! That mean that trade mark owner (Netscape in the past and Sun/Oracle for now) can name JavaScript 1.5/1.6/etc. Seems that Gecko engine take right for use these names...